# How to detect and handle two fingers moving on the canvas in the same time in android?

Tags: android, multi-touch, motionevent

I want to be able to handle two different fingers moving on canvas in the same time but in two different halves of the screen, I know how to handle a two finger tap but i cannot find anywhere how to deal with two fingers move, because there is only one "ACTION_MOVE". i tried to use it and distinguish the by the half they were clicked in, but it just catches the first finger that touches the screen and ignores the other one.
How Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.getActionMasked()` or both:

```
if (event.getAction() == ACTION_MOVE || event.getActionMasked() == ACTION_MOVE)
```